# How to implement drag and drop functionality in Angular Material Table?

Tags: drag-and-drop, angular5, angular-material2, ng2-dragula, angular-cdk

I am able to to implement drag and drop functionality using ng2-dragula but the problem I am facing that it drags the header row as well and also unable to get the dragged row values(its row data )and the row above and below from the dragged row.

Can anyone help me this ?

I also found the same issue on github

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/issues/831

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"
               matSort matSortActive="categoryName" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear
               [dragula]='"seventh-bag"'>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="seqNo">

            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>S.No.</mat-header-cell>

            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row;let i=index;">
              {{(paginator.pageSize * (paginator.pageIndex)) + i+1}}
            </mat-cell>

        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">

            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header (mouseenter)="nameIcon=false" (mouseleave)="nameIcon=true">
              Category Name
              <i *ngIf="nameIcon && sort.active=='join'" class="fa fa-sort"></i>
            </mat-header-cell>

            <mat-cell
                      *matCellDef="let catg;">
                     name
            </mat-cell>

        </ng-container>


        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>

        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
        (click)="selectedRow(row)" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == row._id}"
        (mouseenter) ="dragRow = row"  (mouseleave) ="mouseLeave('div A')"
        >
          {{row}}
        </mat-row>

    </mat-table>
```

When I use the above approach, then I am unable to fetch the dragged row data and its new position

2.) When I implement ng2-dragula

```
 <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
        (click)="selectedRow(row)"  [dragula]='"seventh-bag"'
        >
```

then the drag and drop functionality not works well

Please refer to the picture below

[image: When ng2-dragula implement mat-rows then these things happened]

Image Source:- https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6483007/36256531-4a34b638-124b-11e8-9b13-cd15391886ae.gif

Comment: Hi, I'm struggling with the same problem. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an exact answer to your question regarding dragula but seeing no-one has had a go yet here is a possible solution that seems to be working for me: I tried getting drag and drop working with mat-table as well. I didn't use ng2-dragula (i used jquery ui-sortable in the past), but i did get somewhere with angulars new CDK drag and drop system. (now in 7.0.0).

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

The only issue i had with this is that if you are wanting to do sorting, the cdkDropList directive had to be a direct parent to the cdkDrag elements, not sure if there is a way around this and i couldn't find an option saying otherwise.

seeing that mat-tables don't seem to be constructed in a way that works nicely with d&d I've turned to lists or expansion-panels (if you want the drop down for extended forms on each row) as they seem to behave better when being nested and work well with the drag and drop tools by cdk. (you will  probably need to do some custom styling to get it looking like a table)

I realise it wont come with the sorting, filtering features mat-table comes with but if you are prioritising the d&d you may have to find another way around it.

Hope that gives you something to work with!